iOS Notification Issue ‘Awesome Notification’ in Flutter: Notification Repeats in Foreground, Only Appears Once in Background
iOS Notification Issue ‘Awesome Notification’ in Flutter: Notification Repeats in Foreground, Only Appears Once in Background.
I want the notification to repeat every 7 seconds as I coded. On iOS, It works as expected in the foreground, but in the background, the notification only appears once and disappears. Since it’s an alarm app, I need the notification to keep repeating until the user clicks on it, even in the background. Below is the code I have written.
static void initializeNotificationListeners() {
    print('Initializing notification listeners');

    AwesomeNotifications().setListeners(
      onActionReceivedMethod: onActionReceivedMethod,
      onNotificationDisplayedMethod: onNotificationDisplayedMethod,
    );
    print('Notification listeners set');
  }



static Future<void> onNotificationDisplayedMethod(ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
    
    _notificationTimer?.cancel();

    _notificationTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 7), (timer) async {
      int? subId = int.tryParse(receivedNotification.payload?['subId'] ?? '');

      await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
          criticalAlert: true,
          displayOnBackground: true,
          displayOnForeground: true,
          fullScreenIntent: true,


          id: subId!, 
          channelKey: "alarm_Category",
          title: 'Alarm Reminder',
          body: 'Your alarm is still active!',
          autoDismissible: false,
          payload: receivedNotification.payload,

        ),
      );
    });
  }


Timers don't run in the background on iOS.  You can schedule a local notification to trigger at a particular time or after a particular time has elapsed. You can set notification to repeat, but  they will repeat based on the initial trigger conditions, so if you schedule a notification for "Monday" it will repeat every Monday. If you schedule a notification to trigger in 30 minutes, it will repeat every 30 minutes. You can't configure a notification to fire in 30 minutes and repeat every second. You could schedule 20 or so notifications to fire at intervals of 1 second.

Thank you for the response. In that case, to repeatedly recreate the alarm at second intervals and send notifications when in the background, which library or feature would be recommended?I want the notification to keep sending repeatedly in the background at second intervals until it is clicked.

You can't do that. There is a limit to how many notifications you can schedule (about 20). I presume you can schedule notifications for a specific time with the package you are using; just schedule multiple consecutive notifications.

In the AppDelegate.swift, is it possible to configure the notification sound or repetition? Currently, the sound of the registered alarm in Flutter lasts about 17 seconds, but on iOS, the notification appears and disappears after about 8 seconds. Is there a way to make this display last longer? Is it necessary to create and repeat around 20 alarms in Flutter to achieve this? I understand that iOS has a limit of 64 notifications, and if I create 20 alarms each time, that would result in 60 notifications after generating 3 sets, which would quickly hit the iOS limit of 64.

You don't set the custom sound in the app delegate. You set it when you schedule the notification. The custom sound can be up to 30 seconds long.
